# How to align text & images for multiple iphone sizes

Tags: xcode, autolayout

I am struggling getting the xcode constraints to work properly, I have 6 images and text underneath that is looking bad in larger iphone sizes. It looks fine in iphone SE/8 but for iphone 11 the left and right images hug the sides more.

Here are screen shots of them in iphone SE & 11:
[iphone SE and 11 screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gld6j.png)

Here are the constraints for the images:
[image constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulsHH.png)

And here are the text constraints:
[text constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vuW1.png)

Any feedback greatly appreciated, I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here

Comment: Are you going to be creating this dynamically? Will you always have exactly 6 images?

Comment: It will always have 6 static images

Comment: Are those image views? or buttons with image only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UIStackView` makes this layout rather easy to accomplish...

- put a Button and a Label in a Vertical Stack View... that makes a "column"

  - Alignment: Fill / Distribution: Fill / Spacing: 8
- put 3 of those into a Horizontal Stack View... that makes "Row 1" with 3 "columns"

  - Alignment: Fill / Distribution: Equal Spacing / Spacing: 0
- Do that again, for "Row 2"
- put the 2 "row" stack views in an "outer" Vertical Stack View

  - Alignment: Fill / Distribution: Fill Equally / Spacing: 16

For the constraints, we'll start with the "outer" stack view

- constrain Top 16-pts from bottom of your "banner" view
- constrain Width to 90% of view (width equal to view width, Multiplier: 0.9)
- constrain CenterX to view CenterX
- constrain "btn1" with 1:1 ratio (keeps it "square"), and Width equal to row1 Width, Multiplier: 0.3 (30%)
- constrain "btn2" equal width and height to "btn1"
- constrain "btn3" equal width and height to "btn1"
- constrain "btn4" with 1:1 ratio (keeps it "square"), and Width equal to row2 Width, Multiplier: 0.3 (30%)
- constrain "btn5" equal width and height to "btn4"
- constrain "btn6" equal width and height to "btn4"

Here's how it looks in Storyboard (large image, click to see it better):

[image]

and here is the source code to that Storyboard so you can inspect it (I added images named "b1" / "b2" / etc):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.Storyboard.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="17701" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES" initialViewController="LKM-8A-nb2">
    <device id="retina4_7" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <deployment identifier="iOS"/>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="17703"/>
        <capability name="Safe area layout guides" minToolsVersion="9.0"/>
        <capability name="System colors in document resources" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <scenes>
        <!--Grid View Controller-->
        <scene sceneID="79o-Ox-TwA">
            <objects>
                <viewController id="LKM-8A-nb2" customClass="GridViewController" customModule="PanZoom" customModuleProvider="target" sceneMemberID="viewController">
                    <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="IYJ-Hg-6cW">
                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="667"/>
                        <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" widthSizable="YES" heightSizable="YES"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="P8z-Sm-Q6t" userLabel="BannerView">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="375" height="136"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <imageView clipsSubviews="YES" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="scaleAspectFit" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" image="person.fill" catalog="system" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="4jH-vt-7l5" userLabel="BannerImageView">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="8" y="9.5" width="120" height="117"/>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="4jH-vt-7l5" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="81h-yQ-hei"/>
                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="120" id="uwP-ci-9yv"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </imageView>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Name" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="u6h-2Y-fxg">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="136" y="16" width="231" height="20.5"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="boldSystem" pointSize="17"/>
                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Some Text" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="awQ-9d-ac7">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="136" y="44.5" width="80" height="20.5"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                        <color key="textColor" systemColor="systemBlueColor"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Some More Text" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="kfJ-4l-Yax">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="136" y="73" width="123.5" height="20.5"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                        <color key="textColor" systemColor="systemBlueColor"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                </subviews>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.7673358321" green="0.76744776960000005" blue="0.78157937529999999" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <constraints>
                                    <constraint firstItem="4jH-vt-7l5" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="P8z-Sm-Q6t" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="54V-Ke-kwa"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="u6h-2Y-fxg" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="4jH-vt-7l5" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="C0B-BT-gMX"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="kfJ-4l-Yax" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="awQ-9d-ac7" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="Gge-WX-XeV"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="4jH-vt-7l5" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="P8z-Sm-Q6t" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="VzJ-jF-PeU"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="u6h-2Y-fxg" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="fgo-dg-lvH"/>
                                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="4jH-vt-7l5" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="jOP-Za-STU"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="awQ-9d-ac7" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="u6h-2Y-fxg" secondAttribute="leading" id="p8C-R8-P3n"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="u6h-2Y-fxg" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="P8z-Sm-Q6t" secondAttribute="top" constant="16" id="tpW-8x-5cn"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="awQ-9d-ac7" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="u6h-2Y-fxg" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="wI1-Kb-F4D"/>
                                    <constraint firstItem="kfJ-4l-Yax" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="awQ-9d-ac7" secondAttribute="leading" id="yVa-mI-4gE"/>
                                </constraints>
                            </view>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" distribution="fillEqually" spacing="16" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="kvJ-kl-KIN" userLabel="Outer Stack View">
                                <rect key="frame" x="19" y="152" width="337.5" height="275.5"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" distribution="equalSpacing" spacing="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="sQJ-MU-CSp" userLabel="Row1 Stack View">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="337.5" height="130"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" spacing="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="OTb-dV-ttj" userLabel="R1C1 Stack View">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="101" height="130"/>
                                                <subviews>
                                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="yyV-A5-4ke" userLabel="btn1" customClass="MyButton" customModule="PanZoom" customModuleProvider="target">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="101" height="101.5"/>
                                                        <constraints>
                                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="yyV-A5-4ke" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="P3x-SZ-1Mc"/>
                                                        </constraints>
                                                        <state key="normal" backgroundImage="b1"/>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Text 1" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="1jL-GW-qqq">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="109.5" width="101" height="20.5"/>
                                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                    </label>
                                                </subviews>
                                            </stackView>
                                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" spacing="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="8Q6-9W-gXz" userLabel="R1C2 Stack View">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="118" y="0.0" width="101" height="130"/>
                                                <subviews>
                                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="V37-nh-l7V" userLabel="bn2" customClass="MyButton" customModule="PanZoom" customModuleProvider="target">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="101" height="101.5"/>
                                                        <state key="normal" backgroundImage="b2"/>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Text 2" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Kmm-DY-Y3T">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="109.5" width="101" height="20.5"/>
                                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                    </label>
                                                </subviews>
                                            </stackView>
                                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" spacing="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="rkC-n3-1XR" userLabel="R1C3 Stack View">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="236" y="0.0" width="101.5" height="130"/>
                                                <subviews>
                                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="kEA-jG-33S" userLabel="btn3" customClass="MyButton" customModule="PanZoom" customModuleProvider="target">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="101.5" height="101.5"/>
                                                        <state key="normal" backgroundImage="b3"/>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Text 3" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="xNJ-8c-vjq">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="109.5" width="101.5" height="20.5"/>
                                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                    </label>
                                                </subviews>
                                            </stackView>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstItem="kEA-jG-33S" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="yyV-A5-4ke" secondAttribute="height" id="2Si-on-gKK"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="kEA-jG-33S" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="yyV-A5-4ke" secondAttribute="width" id="50T-Oa-2nZ"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="V37-nh-l7V" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="yyV-A5-4ke" secondAttribute="width" id="MTd-OL-UU7"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="yyV-A5-4ke" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="sQJ-MU-CSp" secondAttribute="width" multiplier="0.3" id="XMH-jn-adE"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="V37-nh-l7V" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="yyV-A5-4ke" secondAttribute="height" id="twm-hP-ffF"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" distribution="equalSpacing" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="gpl-wE-cdj" userLabel="Row2 Stack View">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="146" width="337.5" height="129.5"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" spacing="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="xBX-2X-LgE" userLabel="R2C1 Stack View">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="101" height="129.5"/>
                                                <subviews>
                                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="cXk-UC-q0U" userLabel="btn4" customClass="MyButton" customModule="PanZoom" customModuleProvider="target">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="101" height="101"/>
                                                        <constraints>
                                                            <constraint firstAttribute="width" secondItem="cXk-UC-q0U" secondAttribute="height" multiplier="1:1" id="eod-eh-BtF"/>
                                                        </constraints>
                                                        <state key="normal" backgroundImage="b4"/>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Text 4" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="dVu-b1-jO2">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="109" width="101" height="20.5"/>
                                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                    </label>
                                                </subviews>
                                            </stackView>
                                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" spacing="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Dmz-Yl-dol" userLabel="R2C2 Stack View">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="118" y="0.0" width="101" height="129.5"/>
                                                <subviews>
                                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="M6I-u0-WFF" userLabel="btn5" customClass="MyButton" customModule="PanZoom" customModuleProvider="target">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="101" height="101"/>
                                                        <state key="normal" backgroundImage="b5"/>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Text 5" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="O8J-rz-IMQ">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="109" width="101" height="20.5"/>
                                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                    </label>
                                                </subviews>
                                            </stackView>
                                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" spacing="8" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="k3d-gs-eoH" userLabel="R2C3 Stack View">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="236" y="0.0" width="101.5" height="129.5"/>
                                                <subviews>
                                                    <button opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" contentHorizontalAlignment="center" contentVerticalAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="middleTruncation" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="kTF-VQ-Jbo" userLabel="btn6" customClass="MyButton" customModule="PanZoom" customModuleProvider="target">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="101.5" height="101"/>
                                                        <state key="normal" backgroundImage="b6"/>
                                                    </button>
                                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Text 6" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="9T2-30-xGr">
                                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="109" width="101.5" height="20.5"/>
                                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                                    </label>
                                                </subviews>
                                            </stackView>
                                        </subviews>
                                        <constraints>
                                            <constraint firstItem="M6I-u0-WFF" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="cXk-UC-q0U" secondAttribute="height" id="4OF-bE-18u"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="kTF-VQ-Jbo" firstAttribute="height" secondItem="cXk-UC-q0U" secondAttribute="height" id="RtW-GA-B4z"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="kTF-VQ-Jbo" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="cXk-UC-q0U" secondAttribute="width" id="ZQL-ND-pb9"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="M6I-u0-WFF" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="cXk-UC-q0U" secondAttribute="width" id="lZf-hT-U08"/>
                                            <constraint firstItem="cXk-UC-q0U" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="gpl-wE-cdj" secondAttribute="width" multiplier="0.3" id="zu9-SD-Sf7"/>
                                        </constraints>
                                    </stackView>
                                </subviews>
                            </stackView>
                        </subviews>
                        <viewLayoutGuide key="safeArea" id="itM-WY-yzX"/>
                        <color key="backgroundColor" systemColor="systemBackgroundColor"/>
                        <constraints>
                            <constraint firstItem="itM-WY-yzX" firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="P8z-Sm-Q6t" secondAttribute="trailing" id="TYg-aZ-N52"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="kvJ-kl-KIN" firstAttribute="width" secondItem="IYJ-Hg-6cW" secondAttribute="width" multiplier="0.9" id="cAB-cO-cjP"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="kvJ-kl-KIN" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="P8z-Sm-Q6t" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="16" id="kst-RO-T6D"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="kvJ-kl-KIN" firstAttribute="centerX" secondItem="IYJ-Hg-6cW" secondAttribute="centerX" id="nQx-iz-Die"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="P8z-Sm-Q6t" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="itM-WY-yzX" secondAttribute="leading" id="pEQ-i4-9gg"/>
                            <constraint firstItem="P8z-Sm-Q6t" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="itM-WY-yzX" secondAttribute="top" id="xJS-lS-jlb"/>
                        </constraints>
                    </view>
                </viewController>
                <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="cWX-J6-EFK" userLabel="First Responder" customClass="UIResponder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
            </objects>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="16.800000000000001" y="185.75712143928038"/>
        </scene>
    </scenes>
    <designables>
        <designable name="M6I-u0-WFF">
            <size key="intrinsicContentSize" width="80" height="80"/>
        </designable>
        <designable name="V37-nh-l7V">
            <size key="intrinsicContentSize" width="80" height="80"/>
        </designable>
        <designable name="cXk-UC-q0U">
            <size key="intrinsicContentSize" width="80" height="80"/>
        </designable>
        <designable name="kEA-jG-33S">
            <size key="intrinsicContentSize" width="80" height="80"/>
        </designable>
        <designable name="kTF-VQ-Jbo">
            <size key="intrinsicContentSize" width="80" height="80"/>
        </designable>
        <designable name="yyV-A5-4ke">
            <size key="intrinsicContentSize" width="80" height="80"/>
        </designable>
    </designables>
    <resources>
        <image name="b1" width="80" height="80"/>
        <image name="b2" width="80" height="80"/>
        <image name="b3" width="80" height="80"/>
        <image name="b4" width="80" height="80"/>
        <image name="b5" width="80" height="80"/>
        <image name="b6" width="80" height="80"/>
        <image name="person.fill" catalog="system" width="128" height="120"/>
        <systemColor name="systemBackgroundColor">
            <color white="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="genericGamma22GrayColorSpace"/>
        </systemColor>
        <systemColor name="systemBlueColor">
            <color red="0.0" green="0.47843137254901963" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
        </systemColor>
    </resources>
</document>
```